# $\int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

I have been working on this problem but I am not sure in which direction to head with this.  Am I supposed to do an integration by parts first?

$$\int \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,\mathrm dx$$

This would yield:
$$
\begin{align}
u&=x^{-1/2}\\
v&=-e^{-x}\\
\mathrm du&=-\frac23x^{-3/2}\\
\mathrm dv&=e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx
\end{align}
$$

But then what?

Comment: Please use $\LaTeX$ mode by putting equations within \$ ... \$.

Comment: It's an incomplete Gamma function.  It doesn't have a closed form.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith: I'd say that whether or not it has a closed form depends on the bounds... See my answer.

Comment: @clayton Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Since the problem is tagged `improper-integrals`, I'll assume the bounds are $0$ and $\infty$.

**Hint:** Using an appropriate $u$-substitution, we find $$\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx=2\int_0^\infty e^{-u^2}\,du=\sqrt{\pi}.$$